# Cannot install commit-msg-linter with pnpm: sh: .git/hooks/commit-msg: No such file or directory

Tags: githooks, pnpm, husky, asdf

### Description

I can't install commit-msg-linter, all other hooks work fine.

### Reproduce

```bash
git init

pnpm init
pnpm add -D husky
pnpm add -D git-commit-msg-linter

pnpm exec husky install

git add .
git commit -m "hello"
```

### Result

sh: .git/hooks/commit-msg: No such file or directory
husky - commit-msg hook exited with code 127 (error)
husky - command not found in PATH=/home/zau/.asdf/shims:/home/zau/.asdf/bin:/usr/lib/git-core:/home/zau/.local/share/pnpm:/opt/sonar-scanner/bin:/home/zau/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/home/zau/.yarn/bin:/home/zau/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:/home/zau/.pyenv/shims:/home/zau/.pyenv/bin:/usr/share/pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims:/home/zau/bin:/usr/local/bin:/home/zau/.npm-global/bin:/home/zau/.pyenv/bin:/opt/sonar-scanner/bin:/home/zau/.nix-profile/bin:/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin:/home/zau/.nix-profile/bin:/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/zau/.local/bin:/home/zau/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin

### Specs

Using asdf*

- git: 2.39.1
- pnpm: 7.26.3
- node: 19.6.0
- package.json

```json
{
  "name": "husky-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "git-commit-msg-linter": "^4.5.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.3"
  }
}
```

### Trying

- remove node_modules
- remove .git/hooks

Expect is:

```bash
git commit -m "hello"

  ************* Invalid Git Commit Message **************
  commit message: hello
  Invalid length: Length 5. Commit message cannot be longer than 100 characters or shorter than 10 characters
  correct format: <type>[scope]: <subject>
  example: docs: update README to add developer tips

  type:
    feat     A new feature.
    fix      A bug fix.
    docs     Documentation only changes.
    style    Changes that do not affect the meaning of the code (white-space, formatting, missing semi-colons, etc).
    refactor A code change that neither fixes a bug nor adds a feature.
    test     Adding missing tests or correcting existing ones.
    chore    Changes to the build process or auxiliary tools and libraries such as documentation generation.
    perf     A code change that improves performance.
    ci       Changes to your CI configuration files and scripts.
    build    Changes that affect the build system or external dependencies (example scopes: gulp, broccoli, npm).
    temp     Temporary commit that won't be included in your CHANGELOG.

  scope:
    Optional, can be anything specifying the scope of the commit change.
    For example $location, $browser, $compile, $rootScope, ngHref, ngClick, ngView, etc.
    In App Development, scope can be a page, a module or a component.

  subject:
    Brief summary of the change in present tense. Not capitalized. No period at the end.
  
husky - commit-msg hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ironically, I solved it exactly after posting here, thanks community

If you updated the pnpm version with asdf just run:

```bash
pnpm store prune

rm -rf node_modules

pnpm i
pnpm exec husk install
```

and run:

```bash
git commit -m "hello"

  ************* Invalid Git Commit Message **************
  commit message: hello
  Invalid length: Length 5. Commit message cannot be longer than 100 characters or shorter than 10 characters
  correct format: <type>[scope]: <subject>
  example: docs: update README to add developer tips

  type:
    feat     A new feature.
    fix      A bug fix.
    docs     Documentation only changes.
    style    Changes that do not affect the meaning of the code (white-space, formatting, missing semi-colons, etc).
    refactor A code change that neither fixes a bug nor adds a feature.
    test     Adding missing tests or correcting existing ones.
    chore    Changes to the build process or auxiliary tools and libraries such as documentation generation.
    perf     A code change that improves performance.
    ci       Changes to your CI configuration files and scripts.
    build    Changes that affect the build system or external dependencies (example scopes: gulp, broccoli, npm).
    temp     Temporary commit that won't be included in your CHANGELOG.

  scope:
    Optional, can be anything specifying the scope of the commit change.
    For example $location, $browser, $compile, $rootScope, ngHref, ngClick, ngView, etc.
    In App Development, scope can be a page, a module or a component.

  subject:
    Brief summary of the change in present tense. Not capitalized. No period at the end.
  
husky - commit-msg hook exited with code 1 (error)
```